# Keras LSTM Multiclass Classification for time series

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to classify my input time-series data in 10 response classes. So I have 10 classes in my response feature.

My input data has 40 features and response(y_train) has 1 feature with 10 classes.

```
train input shape (4320, 43), train_y shape (4320,)
```

My LSTM Network looks like following

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(25, dropout=0.2, input_shape=(train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2])))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(train_X, train_y, epochs=10, batch_size=36,  validation_split =0.05)
```

And I get an error

```
Error when checking target: expected dense_21 to have shape (10,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

I think it is happening because I have 1 feature in my *train_y*, where the dense output layer is expecting 10 features. How to run my multiclass time series classification with categorical_entropy loss function?

Also, as soon as I change loss function to **sparse_categorical_entropy**, it runs smooth.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(25, dropout=0.2, input_shape=(train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2])))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(train_X, train_y, epochs=10, batch_size=36,  validation_split =0.05)
```

Please help me to understand the reason behind it. Also, which loss function shall I use for multiclass classification time series?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial error:

`Error when checking target: expected dense_21 to have shape (10,) but got array with shape (1,)`

Would be due to the `y_train`, not converted into a categorical measure. You need to clean the `y_train` data and convert then into your desired 10 classes categorical array through, maybe, one-hot encoding.

In simple terms, `categorical_crossentropy` should only be used on data that is one-hot encoded.

```
[1, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 0]
...
```

Otherwise, `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` deals with integers.

```
1
2
5
3
...
```

Comment: Thanks for that quick help, can you please help me with my LSTM network, where should I add that to_categorical layer/ transform?

Comment: The best place to convert your layer is right after you separate the train data and train labels, just before you split them into train and test cases.